# Как превратить текст в \u0411\u0411

Tags: php

Есть сервис который принимает текст а на выходе отдает строку типа **\u0411\u0411** .

Как сделать так же? Я думаю это какая-то кодировка, может json что ли... но никак не могу вспомнить.

Буду благодарен за информацию.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo json_encode('Сообщение', JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```